# When i have to call [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation] and when i have to stop?

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

If i write something like this:

```
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

how **accurate** are the coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` in `viewWillAppear` and then in didUpdateLocations, when you have a location you can check for the `[horizontalAccuracy][1]` attribute this will

> The radius of uncertainty for the location, measured in meters.
>   (read-only)

You can access the `horizontalAccuracy` in `didUpdateLocations` with this row

```
let horizontalAccuracy: CLLocationAccuracy = manager.location!.horizontalAccuracy
```

If you´re satisfied with the result you can stop the updating otherwise continue.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
     let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
     lat = String(location.latitude)
     long = String(location.longitude)

     let horizontalAccuracy: CLLocationAccuracy = manager.location!.horizontalAccuracy
     if (horizontalAccuracy < 5.0){
         locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
     } 
}
```

If an error occurs you could try again if you want

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    locationManager.requestLocation()
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the first location update could have terrible accuracy. You may not want to stop updating until you get a more accurate location update.

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated the answer, any feedback for this method?

Comment: Something like that would work. It's really depends on what the OP actually needs. I was simply pointing the potential issue. The OP's requirement isn't clear at all.